# Postfix and Send mail from Virtual Host

Tags: postfix, virtualhost

I currently use postfix to send mail using `@domain1.com` addresses, mail reception for this domain are handled directly by my provider (OVH).
So far so good mails are sent using DKIM no problem.

However I got to change my domain name to `domain2.com`. So I bought `domain2.com` and redirected it to the same server as `domain1.com`. 
The problem is that this time I want to use my own Mail server for sending and receiving. So

I did reconfigure postfix to handle Virtual host for `domain2.com`. This works nicely.

Now I would like to `send` email from `domain2.com` AND `domain1.com` but I can't find how to do that since `domain2.com` is a virtual host.

Whenever a mail is sent from a user on my server, it'll have `domain1.com` (myorigin parameter from postfix config ?)

So how would you send mail with a virtual account from `domain2.com`?

Hope I was clear!

Comment: Which client would you like to use to send your mail from `domain2.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a sender address that contains domain2.com, of course.

Comment: Well even if the tone is a bit condescending you're right, for whoever read this, `sendmail` has a `-f` do to such things

Comment: Excuse me ? Where did you mention sendmail(1) ? I am not a mind reader.

Comment: Well I did put that in the tag but it has been edited.

Comment: If you'd tagged it as sendmail that would mean the MTA, not the program...

Comment: Well I'm not into server config/install/mail transport ... So you'll excuse my ignorance and give me the chance to learn peacefully.

Comment: So offload this task to somebody who is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this at the Postfix config level since you have
a uniq config for 2 domains.
You have to work at the MUA ( email client ) level.

If your email client use the EMAIL variable, you can easily achieve sending from `domain2.com` by setting this
variable as follows:

```
EMAIL=bob@domain2.com
export EMAIL
email_client
```

your email client will place the `-f bob@domain2.com` where it suits within the flow of arguments passed to
`sendmail(1)`
which will build a mail with:

```
From bob@domain2.com
```

as wanted.